# How to upload my packages or document classes to CTAN?

Tags: ctan, contribute

I have created a simple yet useful document class. I am interested in uploading this to CTAN so it can be available in TeX distribution out of the box. As a result, I no longer need to setup `texmf` if it is already in the TeX distribution.

I have questions:

1. What is the policy or rule or protocol to upload packages or document classes?
2. Should I create a manual for them?

Comment: Do you think you could refine your question title a bit to make it more distinct from [How can I contribute to CTAN?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/854/how-can-i-contribute-to-ctan)? You seem to be asking about a different aspect of contributing to CTAN.

Comment: A simple Google search provides the answer. This is only to promote your blog and package, is it not? ;-)

Comment: @Harrold: All search engines have been blocked by my router. I hope I can upload my document class as soon as possible so I can shut my blog down to avoid getting wrong impression of this question. :-)

Comment: @Harrold: In this case, I would give xport the benefit of the doubt. xport: You may prove me right/wrong by creating/not creating documentation for your soon-to-be released class.

Comment: Nah, do not take it personally. I was merely joking. @lockstep Of course, I did not meant it as a serious accusation. There are moderators for this job.

Comment: @Harrold: the blog has been deleted as I said above. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually packages and classes are uploaded as DTX files. There is the [`sty2dtx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sty2dtx) script of mine on CTAN which can help you here and also works for class files. Another one is [`makedtx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makedtx). In the first part of the DTX you should add the documentation.
LaTeX manuals for this topic are [`clsguide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide), [`ltxdoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxdoc) and [`doc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/doc).

You also need a small README file with the name and description of you contribution.

Finally everything should be zipped together and uploaded at e.g. http://dante.ctan.org/upload.

Comment: "Usually" was in former times. Nowadays there is no need for a `dtx` file

Comment: @Herbert: What is a nowadays alternative to writing pretty documented code then?

Comment: Yes, my `ydoc` class isn't even finished yet! ;-)

Comment: @Andrey: Have a look on [`codedoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/codedoc), but I like DTX still better.

Comment: @Andrey: there are several alternatives and  I can say only what I do. I have for one package: `<package>.sty`, `<package>.tex` (if a tex version exists), `<package>-doc.tex`, `<package>-doc.bib` and `<package>-doc.pdf`. And of course a short `README`. This configuration is _easy for me_ to handle. But others like `dtk` and others like ...

Comment: Yes, `<package>-doc.tex` is also fine. @all: Please don't call it `<subdir>/manual.tex` which then becomes `manual.pdf` which is very difficult to find with `texdoc`!

Comment: @MartinScharrer ,I don't understand what's  the difference between the sty2dtx                   - or   makedtx - and clsguide.

Comment: @MartinScharrer , I read several answers for you. you mentioned doc  ltxdoc   clsguide   texdoc  sty2dtx  dtxtut  texdoc  makedtx , but am Dizzy  now

Answer (score 9):

[TeX Frequently Asked Questions — Contributing a file to the archives](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-uploads)

Answer (score 6):

Every package without a documentation is not a good package. For uploading it visit http://dante.ctan.org/upload or http://www.tex.ac.uk/upload/