# How to add listings environment to DTX files

Tags: listings, dtx

I am working on my first DTX file and want to add a code example, which shall be printed with `listings`. This works so far, but since the documentation is commented the `listings` code is using a full verbatim input and prints everything commented.

I assume that I have to play with externals files creation, but still the code must be commented to be part of the documentation. Since I am for sure not the first one to handle this problem I would like to know the common solutions.

Comment: Please have a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23892/how-to-upload-my-packages-or-document-classes-to-ctan. You can write a standalone tex-file and then you can use a perl script.

Comment: That's actally a common problem. I wrote my own code as part of my `ydoc` bundle for this kind of listings. Unfortunately, it is still in the alpha stage and not recommended to be used for other users packages.

Comment: @Marco: I have no idea which perl script shall do what for this problem.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: For example: [makedtx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makedtx)

Comment: @Marco: I used sty2dtx. But I do not see what this has to do with the original problem of inserting verbatim material in a dtx file.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: My indetion was to write a normal tex-file with verbatim material and then use one of the scripts. After that you see verbatim material. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like

```
% \iffalse
%<*example>
% \fi
\begin{lstlisting}
first line
second line
...
\end{lstlisting}
% \iffalse
%</example>
% \fi
```

should work, where `example` is an otherwise unused tag (it can be used for any such environment).

The `\iffalse...\fi` prevents the tag from being printed; the tag itself prevents the uncommented code from being included in the `.sty` file after **docstrip** processing.

Comment: It turns out that this code fails to generate a valid sty file. It though works for the pdf file. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35214/generation-of-sty-file-from-dtx-fails for more information.

Answer (score 10):

I've detailed some of how I approach this in [my blog](http://www.texdev.net/index.php?s=texworks%20dtx). I use the `listings` package along with some code adapted from the `listings` documentation:

```
%\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
%\newsavebox{\LaTeXdemo@box}
%\lstnewenvironment{LaTeXdemo}[1][code and example]{^^A
%  \global\let\lst@intname\@empty
%  \expandafter\let\expandafter\LaTeXdemo@end
%    \csname LaTeXdemo@#1@end\endcsname
%  \@nameuse{LaTeXdemo@#1}^^A
%}{^^A
%  \LaTeXdemo@end
%}
%\newcommand*\LaTeXdemo@new[3]{^^A
%  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter
%    {\csname LaTeXdemo@#1\endcsname}{#2}^^A
%  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter
%    {\csname LaTeXdemo@#1@end\endcsname}{#3}^^A
%}
%\newcommand*\LaTeXdemo@common{^^A
%  \setkeys{lst}{
%    basicstyle   = \small\ttfamily,
%    basewidth    = 0.51em,
%    gobble       = 3,
%    keywordstyle = \color{blue},
%    language     = [LaTeX]{TeX},
%    moretexcs    = {
%      examplemacro,
%      ^^A Add you command names here!
%    }
%  }^^A
%}
%\newcommand*\LaTeXdemo@input{^^A
%  \MakePercentComment
%  \catcode`\^^M=10\relax
%  \small
%  \begingroup
%    \setkeys{lst}{
%      SelectCharTable=\lst@ReplaceInput{\^\^I}{\lst@ProcessTabulator}
%    }^^A
%    \leavevmode
%      \input{\jobname.tmp}^^A
%  \endgroup
%  \MakePercentIgnore
%}
%\LaTeXdemo@new{code and example}{^^A
%  \setbox\LaTeXdemo@box=\hbox\bgroup
%    \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname.tmp}^^A
%    \LaTeXdemo@common
%}{^^A
%    \lst@EndWriteFile
%  \egroup
%  \begin{center}
%    \ifdim\wd\LaTeXdemo@box>0.48\linewidth\relax
%      \hbox to\linewidth{\box\LaTeXdemo@box\hss}^^A
%        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%          \LaTeXdemo@input
%        \end{minipage}
%    \else
%      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
%        \LaTeXdemo@input
%      \end{minipage}
%      \hfill
%      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
%        \hbox to\linewidth{\box\LaTeXdemo@box\hss}^^A
%      \end{minipage}
%    \fi
%  \end{center}
%}
%\LaTeXdemo@new{code only}{^^A
%  \LaTeXdemo@common
%}{^^A
%}
```

(This is taken directly from a `.dtx`, hence the apparent comment-out characters!) This can then be used as

```
%\begin{LaTeXdemo}
%  Some clever demo here
%\end{LaTeXdemo}
```

and will typeset the code and the result of the code side-by-side.

I use a three character 'gobble' as the way I tend to lay out my code is to indent by two spaces for each environment, and there is also the `%` to gobble. I also have an optional argument to my demo environment, so I can do things like

```
%\begin{LaTeXdemo}[code only]
%  \usepackage{foo}
%\end{LaTeXdemo}
```

to explain preamble-only stuff and similar 'show code but don't actually execute' material.

If you have stuff which needs to float, you need a different demo, which I set up using the additional lines

```
%\LaTeXdemo@new{code and float}{^^A
%  \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname.tmp}^^A
%  \LaTeXdemo@common
%}{^^A
%  \lst@EndWriteFile
%  \LaTeXdemo@input
%}
```

This again is set up to work with an optional argument to the environment, and avoids placing the float inside a box (which will fail).

Comment: This is close to my current implementation of my templatedemo package. It would be worth to generalize such approaches in a package. However I am using filecontents and lstinputlisting as a result of some discussion here within the last days. Anyway: do you have an example dtx file demonstrating the usage of your code?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech See my packages on CTAN (perhaps `achemso` would be best - no LaTeX3 stuff but relatively big). See also http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/