# Wrote a new package. Is there some standard place to share?

Tags: symbols, package-writing, ctan

So I finished writing my package for typesetting [Begriffsschrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift). I think it marks a marked improvement over the package begriff, which is the only other package for the same purpose, that I can find out there. Since there might be the odd philosopher/logician out there that has a use for it, and I've already gone through the trouble of writing some documentation for it. I was wondering whether there is some standard place to share packages. I have a plain .sty file a .tex and .pdf documentation file, and a copy of GNU. (Since the package is partially based on the begriff package which was released under GNU, I better do the same.)

Comment: CTAN is the standard medium to upload a package.

Comment: See [How to upload my packages or document classes to CTAN?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23892) and [How can I contribute to CTAN?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/854/) for more detail.

Comment: Congrats to your new package & +1! `:)`

Comment: Yay, congrats! `:)` Besides of uploading the package to CTAN, you can also use a code repository such as GitHub or BitBucket to host stuff and keep track of issues and improvements. Some examples of packages in this deployment model include [`siunitx`](https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx) and [`adjustbox`](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox). `:)`

Comment: I think I will stick with just CTAN for now. Thanks for all the above answers/comments. Since the question has effectively been answered in the comments is there some way of marking it as answered despite the lack of a formal "answer"?

Comment: FWIW I take it you have seen [this](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/begriff).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Congratulations for your new package and thank you for taking your time for the documentation too.

For the packages to reach to the widest audience and to be able to be updated in a structured way via various update mechanisms, [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/) is the standard medium to upload a package.

As Joseph Wright commented, see

- [How to upload my packages or document classes to CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23892/how-to-upload-my-packages-or-document-classes-to-ctan)
- [How can I contribute to CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/854/how-can-i-contribute-to-ctan)
- [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25116/2693)

for more details.