# Adding languages to package blindtext

Tags: languages, polyglossia, indic, blindtext

When we use package `blindtext` with a specific language loaded by packages like `babel` or `polyglossia`, we can generate a sample document with some text in that particular language. Right now blind-texts for all languages are not ready. eg. Many indic languages like Marathi, Hindi, Sanskrit, Bengali.

Generating blind-text for languages is not a difficult task as the speakers of that language can provide it, but how to make that tex-source readable by the package? I have formed some blindtext for Marathi language, I would like to add it with other languages. Can somebody help?

Comment: As you can see in the [`blindtext` tree](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext), only Catalan, English, French, German and Latin are supported. You can contact the authors of `blindtext` and send them your own `blindtext_marathi.dtx`. However, I think you should instead make a new package.

Comment: Ok thanks, how can I submit a new package?

Comment: You can read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/854/203621) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23892/203621) or [here](https://ctan.org/help/submit). They are very detailed.

Comment: [`lipsum`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) also has an interface to define new *lorem ipsum* texts, see https://github.com/patta42/lipsum/commit/217afb1e4faf0a10b5f74abd1119fd2b76ad882f and the relevant bits of the documentation.