# How to make a CTAN package MiKTeX friendly?

Tags: miktex, best-practices, package-writing, ctan

I've heard that it is difficult to install my new [`statrep`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/statrep) package using MiKTeX. The `dtx` file is self-extracting, but I think MiKTeX doesn't expect to work with a `dtx` file.

Can someone provide a "best practice" for a CTAN package bundle that is friendly for MiKTeX, TeX Live, and manual installation?  Perhaps including the *.sty files and a plain *.ins file even though the `dtx` is self-extracting?

Comment: You can use ctanify.

Comment: See: [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25116)

Comment: I provide all my packages as DTX plus INS file, but also as TDS ZIP file where all files are already extracted and in the correct sub-folder. I never had an issue with getting my packages into TeX Live or MiKTeX.

Comment: In my opinion this has nothing to do with MiKTeX! The only problem may be, that MiKTeX perhaps is used by less experienced users, who probably don’t know, where to put the created files. Also in the `README` the install procedure fits only to TeXlive. If you create a TDS ZIP file, as Martin already wrote, all should go fine and probably your package will be integrated into the distributions then. (For package installing into a local TeXMF in MiKTeX you will find answers here at least by me.) Beside that is there an external SAS program needed and if yes does exist a windows version?

Comment: I'm not complaining about MikTeX, but if it expects a `.ins` file, then I should not upload a self-extracting `.dtx` file (and do exactly as Martin says). This seems like important information for package authors if a package that only includes a self-extracting `.dtx` file, omitting the `.ins` file, creates problems for MikTeX users.   Also, SAS runs on unix and windows.

Comment: @TimA: Self-extracting `.dtx` are rare, so I'm not surprised that Christian doesn't care for them. Use an `.ins` or ask Christian Schenk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is best for MiKTeX is ultimately up to Christian Schenk. However, for a `.dtx`-style package CTAN usually ask for:

- The `.dtx`
- The `.ins` to unpack it
- The documentation (in PDF format)

That is what I upload for 'self-extracting' `.dtx` files, and this seems to work well.