# How to get a package into texlive

Tags: texlive, distributions

Say I have written an awesome package called "worldpeace.sty" and uploaded it to CTAN. What can I do to get the package in to texlive?

Comment: There's some tips on Tug.org: http://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html

Comment: _You_ already have some packages on TL. `:-)`

Comment: @MartinSchröder The tl2012 was missing my latest and greatest contribution ;-) (Now it's in there automatically)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TUG has a page with information about contributing packages to TeX Live:

- http://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html

(From [the TeX Live page](http://tug.org/texlive/), click [*How can you help*](http://tug.org/texlive/contribute.html) then [*advice and requests for contributing packages*](http://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html).)

Most important, [upload to CTAN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-is-good-practice-when-preparing-a-package-for-ctan) with a free license (e.g. [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/) or [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html)). In addition, include source code for any documentation, don't have `@` in filenames, and watch for name conflicts.

Comment: Nice answer, but perhaps a few key points might go in here (basically 'upload to CTAN with a free license')?

Comment: @JosephWright Yeah, you're right. I'll update in a bit.

Comment: As an Official Package Author with a 100% record at getting my packages into TeXLive, I can confirm that the "upload to CTAN with a suitable licence" is the key step as it's all that I did for those (two!) packages.